# How to check if data exists before writing to table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have a SQL command which inserts data into a table in `SSMS` called `FileTrackLog`.

My app crashes everytime I insert duplicate data as [Path] field is a `primary key`.

How can I check how to not re-add data that already exists, without crashing my app?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd =
                    new SqlCommand(
                        "INSERT INTO [FileTrackLog] (Date, Client, Path, DateAddedToDb) " + // Dont foreget to add "DateAddedToDb" later when going live
                        " VALUES (@Date, @Client, @Path, @DateAddedToDb)"); // Dont foreget to add @"DateAddedToDb" later when going live
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", DbType.DateTime);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Client", DbType.String);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Path", DbType.String);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(@"DateAddedToDb",DbType.DateTime);

                foreach (var extractedRecord in extractedList)
                {   
                    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = extractedRecord.Date;
                    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = extractedRecord.Client;
                    cmd.Parameters[2].Value = extractedRecord.Path;
                    cmd.Parameters[3].Value = DateTime.Now;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `EXISTS`, we can check the value already exist or not.

If the value already exists, it skips the insertion progress.

Try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [FileTrackLog] WHERE YourPrimaryKeyColumn = @PrimaryKeyInput)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [FileTrackLog] (Date, Client, Path, DateAddedToDb)
    VALUES (@Date, @Client, @Path, @DateAddedToDb)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO [FileTrackLog] (Date, Client, Path, DateAddedToDb)
SELECT @Date, @Client, @Path, @DateAddedToDb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [FileTrackLog] WHERE Path = @Path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `NOT EXISTS` check before `INSERT` command i.e.,-

```
SqlCommand cmd =
           new SqlCommand(
           "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [FileTrackLog] WHERE Path = @Path) "+
           "INSERT INTO [FileTrackLog] (Date, Client, Path, DateAddedToDb) " +
           "VALUES (@Date, @Client, @Path, @DateAddedToDb)");
```

Also, You want to track whether `insertion` is successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

I consider you will be usefull to use [Merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command to realize a AddOrUpdate paradigm in your application.

```
MERGE [FileTrackLog]  AS target  
    USING (SELECT _PrimeryKeyValue, _Date, _Client, _Path, _DateAddedToDb) AS source (@PrimaryKeyValue, @Date, @Client, @Path, @DateAddedToDb)  
    ON (target.YourPrimaryKeyColumn  = source._PrimeryKeyValue)  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN   
        UPDATE SET Date = source._Date, Client = source._Client, Path = source._Path
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
    INSERT (Date, Client, Path, DateAddedToDb)  
    VALUES (source._Date, source._Client, source._Path, source._DateAddedToDb)
```

If the condition in `ON` statement is matched with any rows in the target table
then we will update data in the target table(except a column `DateAddedToDb`).Otherwise we will insert new row in the target table.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the exception and accordingly handle it.

```
foreach (var extractedRecord in extractedList)
{   
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = extractedRecord.Date;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = extractedRecord.Client;
    cmd.Parameters[2].Value = extractedRecord.Path;
    cmd.Parameters[3].Value = DateTime.Now;

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 2627)
        {
            //Violation of primary key. Handle Exception
            //continue to next iteration
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps

```
Insert into TableX
select 
    A
    ,B

from (
VALUES ('1', '2')) as t
where A not in select A from TableX
```

EDIT: yes, there are other ways, but this way is useful if you want to insert multiple lines in the same insert.